# facebook app on heroku, shared and free database where is getting started guide for free database?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, facebook-apps

I was just trying to setup my first app on heruko...

As it says it provides 5mb's shared database free postgre database setup ready

but where are credentials for already setup database and getting started guide for the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FB app docs are here:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

You should've received an email to confirm your Heroku account. That'll give you access to your credentials.

Database docs are here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database

And there are specific tutorials for the connecting to your database from each language.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I mean... credentials for postgre database and how to setup guide for free postgre database..??  this is nowhere

Comment: is  it possible to setup postgree shared database without account verification i.e without providing them credit card details??

Comment: no, you don't need credit card for that. It's one of the few addons that you can have without a validated account.